# CCLayer staying the background

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game im working on where I have multiple scenes and in some of them I used the drag/drop tutorial from ray wenderlich's site (i.e. my in game store). I am using

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFadeTR transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]]];
```

or similar to change between scenes (gameplay, store, main menu, etc...) and I have noticed that when I change the scene it seems to just move the new layer on top of the other one. This is a huge issue im dealing with because if you go to the store scene (which has the drag/drop code in it) and then go back to the main menu (does not have drag/drop) and tap and drag anywhere it crashes my game. Its crashing (i believe) because it is trying to move a layer that is not there. Any idea how to fix this?

I have also tried using [HelloWordLayer node] instead of [HelloWordLayer scene] and there is no difference.

Comment: check if the scene you're leaving runs its dealloc method. My guess is that it's leaking.

Comment: There is no dealloc method added in the scene, I thought cocos2d released everything in the scene when replaceScene was called?

Comment: So it seems as if the gesture recognizer I am using never gets released for some reason. I am not entirely sure of the reasoning. I tried adding 

[gestureRecognizer release];

to my dealloc for the layer but it made no difference. I did find a way to get around the bug (probably not the most correct way but it works) by adding this to my dealloc:

gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

Comment: does the layer's dealloc run? If not the entire layer is leaking.

Comment: yes the layers dealloc runs. Its weird I have the same exactly code for the gesture recognizer on another layer/scene and I havent had an issue with that one. I added the gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; to the layers dealloc and it works like a charm

Comment: something's fishy though

Comment: I agree but I cant seem to figure out what it is. Im telling you it is the same exact code for the gesture recognizer as another layer I have with the exception of the name of the gestureRecognizer (I duplicated the files and changed the names) and this is the only one that I am having issues with